# Using SQL to find total amount donated to organizations

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with 2 columns,

```
organization_id,
amount_donated
```

I want to return a new table with 2 columns,

```
organization_id 
total_amount_donated
```

How would I go about finding the total amount donated to each organization? I am thinking I have to use GROUP BY but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you do want to use `GROUP BY`. This is because you need to use the `SUM` aggregate function, and by using `GROUP BY organization_id` you will sum the amounts corresponding to each organization.

```
SELECT organization_id, SUM(amount_donated) AS total_amount_donated
FROM your_table
GROUP BY organization_id
```

This is pretty simple SQL, you should probably get your hands on a tutorial or a book to step you through the basics. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select organisation_id,sum(amount_donated) as total_amt_donated from your_table
group by organisation_id
```

You can query like this

Answer (score 0):

You should't to create table, because it will create duplicate data. Instead create a VIEW.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_total_donation
AS
SELECT organization_id, SUM(amount_donated) tot_donation
FROM   table1
GROUP BY organization_id
```